# Magento 2.3: product quantity shows negative value but I have the backorders disabled

Tags: product, stock, backorder

why I have negative stock qty? I don't enable the backorders options and any products show negative values. Any idea?  Working in Magento 2.3. Regards.

Comment: Hey, do you have an external stock manager? It happened to me because the stock wasn't syncd between both. Regarding that you can do a test, put a product with 0 stock and try to do an order and see if it's possible. Side note: if you're using a external stock manager I advise disabling the inv manager of magento, it would disable the salable stock and work like magento 2.2. Hope it helps :D

Comment: @Erich Hans Merz Diaz did you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @SurajPrajapat Apparently it is for the salable quantity, Magento runs a cron at midnight that empties the inventory_reservations table but in my environment I think it was not doing it. Try deleting the records for a specific SKU and tests if the salable quantity changes.

Comment: yes @ErichHansMerzDiaz i tested the same thing and that worked i trubcared the inventory_reservations table problem solved.